# The requested resource () is not available. (when running Tomcat 7.0 after downloading of JSF 2.0 project)

Tags: eclipse, svn, tomcat

I have created a new Dynamic Web Project in eclipse 3.6.

I added a Tomcat 7.0 server and choose "Run on server" on a jsf file. Working fine!

I added it to a SVN repository to share it with other.

I close Eclipse.

I create a new fresh workspace to check that everything works okey. Checking out the same project as above.

I added a Tomcat 7.0 server and choose "Run on server" on the same file as before. This result in a 404: **"HTTP Status 404 .... - description The requested resource () is not available."**

Why is that?? This is really strange! Don't you think? Can you please help me?

Best regards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the dynamic web project from the Tomcat server and add it again.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I tried your suggestion, unfortunately it still does not work. I also tried to clean the webapps (or corresponding in eclipse) directory and republish. How do I enable logging? I cant see any logs in:  .../workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/

Comment: This is why I love stack overflow ... thanks for the answer, worked for me too.

Comment: Is this like a bug or anything? But the solution worked. thanks

Comment: Haha! Worked for me as well. After trying out stuff for about two hours, I find this solution and it works!